# Getting the url's of all open tabs with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can read the URL of the current page, but is it possible to read the url's of all open tabs?

Thanks!

Comment: This should never be possible.

Comment: What is your motivation?

Comment: What I wanted to do was a little app that allowed me to store my open tabs through the click of a bookmarklet, save it to my server, and then I could access the app from another PC and reopen the tabs. Sort of like the "continue session" feature of most modern browsers, but in the cloud; seen as I change computers often - which can disturb my workflow.

Answer (score 8):

No. It is not possible, unless it's being done from a Firefox extension or something similar.

I'm sure you can see why this would lead to all sorts of privacy issues.

Comment: "It is not possible..." "... unless it's being done from a Firefox extension". Then it *is* possible?

Comment: With a browser extension yes

Comment: @nicolaides is correct within the context of the question; it's not possible with jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the client-side.

What is your motivation?

You should never have the need to do this.

Comment: Is there any way to do it? Maybe with a GreaseMonkey script?

Comment: No, you have no business on what other sites are open in other tabs/windows.

Comment: You could do it with a browser add-on, but who'd want to install it?