# Is there any way we can bring the application window to focus by providing its title in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, applescript

I want to bring an application window to focus by its the window title:

Something like this :

```
  function focusWindow(windowTitle){     
           // code to bring the window with that title to the foreground/focus
     }
```

I want to do something similar to this : 
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/getDisplayMedia/

After we click testGetDisplayMedia API button -> Application window and then choose any of the desktop application the window selected is brought to focus, which is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You can't access other windows unless you do it from a parent window. Something similar's been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702864/getting-the-urls-of-all-open-tabs-with-jquery-javascript/1702875

Comment: @JoseVasquez I want to access a desktop application window (please visit the link provided in the desc )

Comment: The thing is you are trying to reproduce WebRTC which is a specific group of protocols working behind. When it comes to select tabs from your current window, you can request the permissions needed by doing this on Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/request  or Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.

Comment: @JoseVasquez I understand the permission issue, but I am not developing a web application, I want this functionality for an electron project in which I am getting the window title through a process and then I want to bring the application window(for example vscode, chrome, terminal window) of that title to focus

Comment: When you say "in electron" (post title), do you mean you wish to execute such a function from inside an ElectronJS app, or you are wishing to reference the window by the title displayed in the ElectronJS app?